# Get selected value from StdContentComboBox

Tags: .net, openxml, openxml-sdk, docx

I would like to get the selected value from a StdContentComboBox, this is a Content control placed in a docx document. I need to get the selected value in .NET, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("yourDocPath", true))
{
    var sdtElements = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>();
    var contentControlsWithComboBoxes = sdtElements.Where(x => x.SdtProperties.Elements<SdtContentComboBox>().Any());

    var contentRuns =
        contentControlsWithComboBoxes.Select(x => x.Elements<SdtContentRun>());
    var selectedValues  = contentRuns.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault().InnerText); // Your selected combobox values 

}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I have found however, that getting the inner text for the associated SdtBlock of the SdtContentComboBox gives you the text for the selected item.